# Weird "Bus error" in string::string constructor

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, freebsd

I've been testing part of my code responsible for filling multimap object, when a weird error started to pop up:

```
int SetPortName(string ID, string Name)
    cout << "ID: " << ID << " Name: " << Name;
    ...
}
```

works fine under non-root user in FreeBSD 5.4, but crashes with "Bus error" while ran under root.

Comment: You don't seriously expect us to diagnose yopur problem from this, do you?

Answer (score 2):

The title mentions something about `string`'s constructor, but since you don't show any code that calls a constructor, I'm forced to assume the problem is actually in the *caller* of this function, where two `string` objects would be constructed for the parameters. My guess is that one of your two actual parameters is a `char*`, and it's a null pointer. Use your debugger to investigate further.

Comment: nice bit of psychic debugging.